# Error in colMeans(adult_csv[1], na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r

i am trying to obtain the means of the age field of [this](https://courses.cs.ut.ee/MTAT.03.183/2017_spring/uploads/Main/adult.csv) dataset.
I have cleaned it. but when i run

```
colMeans(adult_csv[1], na.rm = TRUE)
```

it complains with:

```
Error in colMeans(adult_csv[1], na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

i have tried the `adult_csv[1]` and it correctly gives me the `age` feature.
also there is no `x` or missing data in it.

Comment: Please check the `str(adult_csv[1])`.  You are doing on a single column, why do you need `colMeans`

Comment: the x is there referring to your data source. The function is defined by colMeans(x , ...) in the package so it gives you its default instead of your data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using read.csv, there are a some characters in the age column that causes R to read the whole column as a character vector and not numeric. For the hist function to work, all the data needs to be class numeric.

First look at:

```
adult_csv[which(is.na(as.numeric(adult_csv[1]))), 1]
```

There are a bunch of "?" values which R can't use when calculating histogram. These should be NA values anyways since "?" is just a placeholder for missing data. When you convert this column to numeric, R will give you a warning that it can't convert "?" into a number. Instead it will use NA, but that's probably a good result in your case.

Use:

```
adult_csv[1] <- as.numeric(adult_csv[1])
```

When you're importing data, just take a moment to look for this kind of stuff and learn what the error messages mean. There are also lots of other questions on stack overflow that answer this same question.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: i am using `read.csv` and now i face with `Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

Comment: Hard to debug without knowing how you imported your data. I just used:

adult_csv <- read.csv("https://courses.cs.ut.ee/MTAT.03.183/2017_spring/uploads/Main/adult.csv", header = T, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = F)